# Geolocation success/error callbacks?

Tags: html, meteor

I am using the `mgd:geolocation` package and documentation seems to be scarce. Does anyone know if there is a callback for success and/or error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have an error call `Geolocation.error()`

I found this here: https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/tree/master/packages/mdg:geolocation#geolocationerror